# Finding probability on ribbon

Tags: probability

So a textile manufacturer usually finds 3 defects in every 10 meters of ribbon that he produces. I need to find the probability of finding more than 3 defects in 10 meters of ribbon.

$$p = 3/10 $$
$$q= 7/10 $$
$$P(x>3) = 1 -  [p(x=0)+(x=1)+(x=2)+(x=3)]$$

p=3/10 seem strange so how to find out the p when the question hasn't given the total number of defective.

Comment: Cite such a question.

Comment: You have to model the distribution somehow...typical answer here would be a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with mean $3$.

Comment: Thanks you i got it now. It was obviously a poisson distribution.